# How to Json data parse to tablayout in kotlin?

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

I have an json data. I want to parse it to the tabs.
when I use postman and send request. 
result repsonse this image.
[image]

I already set interface API, and tried to call back response using retrofit. but I got fail. Check my code and How can I fix ViewPagerAdapter and MainActivity? Anyone can help?

Interface API

```
interface API{
    @Headers("Content=Type:application/json","Authorization:token:String")


    @GET("/store/category/info")
    fun getcategory(@Header("Authorization") token: String?):Call<Category>
}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  lateinit var  tabLayout:TabLayout
  lateinit  var viewPager: ViewPager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val token = SharedPreference.getTokenInfo(applicationContext)

        Client.retrofitService.getcategory(token).enqueue(object:Callback<Category>{

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Category>, response: Response<Category>) {
                Log.d("test","Category complete")
                viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager) as ViewPager
                setupViewPager(viewPager)
                tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.category_tab_layout) as TabLayout
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Category>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("test","Category fail")
            }

        })
    }
    private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager) {
        var adapter: ViewPagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        viewPager.adapter = adapter

    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
class ViewPagerAdapter: FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private val mFragmentList: MutableList<Fragment> = mutableListOf()
    private val mFragmentTitleList: MutableList<Child> = mutableListOf()

    constructor(manager: FragmentManager) : super(manager)


    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {

        return mFragmentList.get(position)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {

        return mFragmentList.size

    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {

        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position).title
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val token = SharedPreference.getTokenInfo(applicationContext)
                viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager) as ViewPager
                tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.category_tab_layout) as TabLayout

        Client.retrofitService.getcategory(token).enqueue(object:Callback<Category>{

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Category>, response: Response<Category>) {
                Log.d("test","Category complete")
                setupViewPager(viewPager)
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Category>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("test","Category fail")
            }

        })
    }
```